# Column postqs_id cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have postqs table and reply table. postqs_id is foriegn key in reply table. why im i getting this error?and how to solve it

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'postqs_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `reply_qs` (`reply`, `postqs_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (kk, , 2017-10-27 13:54:03, 2017-10-27 13:54:03))

Controller:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
   $reply = new Reply_qs();
   $reply->reply = $request->get('reply');
   $reply->postqs_id = $request->get('postqs_id');
   $postqs=$reply->postqs()->get();
   $reply->save();

    return redirect()->route('postqs.show')
                    ->with('success','Your question created successfully');
 }
```

postqs Model:

```
 public function reply_qs(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Reply_qs');
   }
```

reply_qs Model:

```
 public function postqs(){
 return $this->belongsTo('App\Postqs', 'postqs_id', 'id');
    }
```

migration:

```
  Schema::create('reply_qs', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id')->unique();
        $table->text('reply');
        $table->timestamps('date');

       $table->integer('postqs_id')->unsigned();
       $table->foreign('postqs_id')->references('id')->on('postqs') -
      >onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

blade file:

```
   <form action="{{ route('postqs.store') }}" method="POST" class="form-
     horizontal">
   {{ csrf_field() }}

         <div class="form-group">
           <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >Reply:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <textarea name="reply" id="reply" class="form-control"></textarea>
              </div>
           </div>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" >
```

Comment: The error says that this line `$request->get('postqs_id');` is returning `null`.

Comment: @Jackowski may i know how to solve it

Comment: Sure. I can try. Do you have a `form`? Show the code please.

Comment: in your form input/select, do you have `name="postqs_id"`?

Comment: @Jackowski i edited the code.please have a look

Comment: @Option it is insert query .

Comment: You need a field inside your form with the `postqs_id` value.

Comment: @Option. yes. but the problem is after submit the reply it is not storing the id of the post that i replied in database. and it  shows the id in the show question url.

Comment: @Option  Route::post('/reply', ['uses'=>'Reply_qsController@store','as'=>'postqs.store']);

Comment: @kavi, Ok so you have no number within the reply it should be reply/{id} as example. I have edited my answer please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So running off of assumptions until clarified...

This is an example of your Routes:

```
Route::get('/url/{id}', 'SomeController@view')->name('postqs.show');

Route::post('/reply/{id}', 'Reply_qsController@store')->name('postqs.store');
```

Your routes will / should look something like this.

Therefore within the controller, you'd do:

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    $storeIt = $request->get();

    MODELNAME::create([
        'reply' => $storeIt['reply'],
        'postqs_id' => $id
        //Other entries here if required
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('postqs.show')
        ->with('success', 'Your question has been created');
}
```

MODELNAME will need to be changed to the model for the relevant table you're intending on storing the information into.

Answer (score -1):

Just Edit Your Form

```
<form action="{{ route('postqs.store') }}" method="POST" class="form-
   horizontal">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
<input name="postqs_id"  display="hidden" class="form-control" value=
 {{$postqs_id}} />
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >Reply:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <textarea name="reply" id="reply" class="form-control"></textarea>
           </div>
        </div>
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" >
```

Comment: You should explain OP where `postqs_id` came from.

Comment: Maybe this form in postqs show page, so get this id from postqs tabel details

Comment: postqs_id is id in postqs table. i want to store the id as a foreign key in reply_qs table.

Comment: Your relationship  is A question has multiple reply, am i correct ? @kavi

Comment: Your reply from is in your question details page ? @kavi

Comment: Just your Question ID pass hiddenly  from your form 

        <input name="postqs_id"  display="hidden" class="form-control" 
     value=
      {{$postqs_id}} />


$postqs_id=your Question details id

Comment: if you use resource route 
Then just your controller change a single line 

      $reply->postqs_id = request('postqs_id'); @kavi

Comment: @Al-Amin, the route isn't determining the id this is the ops problem from my understanding.